# UNIX Console inside browser

Tags: browser, browser-addons, shell, plugins, console

Is there a server-side script, or better yet a browser plugin (for FF or Chrome, I guess) that gives you a REAL UNIX Console inside the browser.

The point being to get a full-fledged system inside a browser-only distro.

Comment: If you're asking about how to get shell (console) access to the local computer, the one on which the web browser is running, there are security restrictions in place to prevent that.

Comment: I think he means Chrome-OS or something like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several java applications that run in browser that can serve as a ssh client. Webmin distributes one in their software. Searching google has turned up quite a few options.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [phpshell](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/) - It has been a while since I've used it, so I don't really know how good it is today. But, obviously, your machine will either need to run a webserver & php or you need to have the capacity to install this.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching virtual terminals if its X based (control alternate Fx) or Ctrl+Alt+T if its chromium.

If its trying to connect to a ssh server you want- Firstly i'd warn that this is terribly insecure, and probably defeats the purpose of ssh.

On the other hand, if you did want a web based terminal, especially for use with a smartphone [webshell](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mressl/webshell/index.html) is pretty good - it even has an on screen keyboard. The design is a bit iphone centric, i suppose but it'll work on any modern web browser, and it easy to setup.